# How can I install Cybersource using composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, cybersource

I wanted to try and install the Cybersource package on Magento. On the marketplace, I had the option to download the package. When I did the only thing in the download was this `composer.json`-

```
{
"name": "cybersource/global-payment-management",
"description": "CyberSource Global Payment Management",
"version": "3.1.5",
"type": "metapackage",
"require": {
    "cybersource/module-3dsecure": "3.1.5",
    "cybersource/module-account-updater": "3.1.1",
    "cybersource/module-address": "3.1.2",
    "cybersource/module-applepay": "3.1.0",
    "cybersource/module-atp": "3.1.0",
    "cybersource/module-bank-transfer": "3.1.0",
    "cybersource/module-core": "3.1.2",
    "cybersource/module-echeck": "3.1.1",
    "cybersource/module-klarna": "3.1.1",
    "cybersource/module-paypal": "3.1.1",
    "cybersource/module-secure-acceptance": "3.1.5",
    "cybersource/module-tax": "3.1.2",
    "cybersource/module-visa-checkout": "3.1.0"
},
"license": [
    "proprietary"
]
}
```

I tried to use the `require cybersource/global-payment-management` when I did this is the error I got-

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find a matching version of package cybersource/global-payment-management. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

I looked on packagist but didn't see the package. This is a really common product. How can I install this with the composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `composer require cybersource/global-payment-management` should work when executed from your Magento root folder. The following might prevent it:

1. `repo.magento.com` was removed from the repositories section of your `composer.json` file
2. The login credentials used to access `repo.magento.com` are different to the user that placed the order in the Marketplace see the documentation for generating access keys [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)
3. Adobe has not yet placed the package into your repo.magento.com repository - you would need to follow up with Magento Marketplace support if this is the case

Comment: I just updated to 2.3.4 using composer last week with no issues so I don't think it is that. I also tried this morning and still nothing.

Comment: I added to the wrong repo.magento account. So you were correct

Answer (score 2):

I have installed the module in 2.4 and found the same error.
[image]

This is working now, Please find the below steps:

> Go to the marketplace account https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/ and create an access key.
> Go to project path and create an auth.json file or copy auth.json.sample and rename it with auth.json.
> Please add your key like(I have mixed the text inside the key)

```
{
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "2bb6569b77'mycode'772362e5ea22bb1",
        "password": "27c4e2eb'edited'378fa5f408a4516b"
    }
}
```

}

> Then after that run the below command

> *composer require cybersource/global-payment-management*

> Now it's working fine. Hope this helps you!

> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Cybersource Global Payment Management Extension for Magento 2 Composer Install

---

**Install Cybersource using via Composer**

- aws ec2 Magento 2.3.2, ubuntu, nginx, php 7.2, mariadb,

> Maksure Ram value more than 4GB before the composer install

```
free -h
```

**Install extension via Composer**

> go to your magento 2 installation directory

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

> get 'superuser' / 'root' user privileges

```
sudo su
```

> Start installation

```
composer require cybersource/global-payment-management
```

> Enable Module s

```
php bin/magento module:enable CyberSource_AccountUpdater
CyberSource_Address CyberSource_ApplePay CyberSource_Atp
CyberSource_BankTransfer CyberSource_Core CyberSource_ECheck
CyberSource_KlarnaFinancial CyberSource_PayPal
CyberSource_SecureAcceptance CyberSource_Tax CyberSource_VisaCheckout
```

> Compile Deploy and Upgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> Restart

```
sudo reboot
```

---

store > Configuration > Sales

*enjoy*